# Can't establish connection because the destination computer expressly denied such a connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using XAMPP, and I can run MySQL (phpMyAdmin) with no problem.

But when I try to run Apache (clicking the Admin buttom in XAMPP) it shows me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(7): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'root', '', 'recepcion_servi...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7

So basically It can't establish connection because the destination computer expressly denied such a connection.
And I can't figure it out why.
I have all config files correct, with the ports, and the user, password for MySQL (root and no password).

And my file when I try to use a simple line of PHP to try to connect to the database is this:

```
<?php
echo "111";
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","recepcion_servicio");
echo "hola";
?>
```

So that's the only thing that I'm trying to do and the error is still there.

Comment: Upon closer inspection this question has nothing to do with phpMyAdmin or Apache. Please tag appropriately. It looks like you are trying to connect to MySQL from PHP

Comment: Is mysql running? Can you connect using `mysql` in command line?

Comment: MySQL is not running and/or the port/socket is not open/accessible. Also `localhost` will cause MySQL to attempt to use the Unix socket file, rather than TCP. If you want TCP use `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Yes I think MySQL is running, because i can acces to phpMyAdmin and create tables and do things there.. But i don't know about command line, i'm ussing Xampp to try all of this to work